# How can I extract the maximum value of Overhead column and Shared Object name in perf top?

Tags: bash, performance, extract, real-time, perf

I use `perf top` command to look at the system performance. As a result, I get a table that is updated in real time:

```
# Overhead       Shared Object       Symbol                           
# ........  ..................  .................................
#
     2.02%           ob1                 [.] 0x00007f3a87f3bd9f
     1.46%           ob2                 [.] 0x00007fb49f374d9f
     1.34%           ob3                 [.] 0x00007f3a87f3bd06
     1.30%           ob4                 [.] 0x00007f3a87f3f07f
     1.11%           ob5                 [.] 0x00007f3a88fb45b7
```

I need to extract maximum Overhead value and the corresponding Shared Object name after each update of the table. Please tell me how this can be done? I'm new to bash.

Comment: I've never heard of `perf top` but it sounds like it's output is similar to that produced by regular Unix `top` and, if so, then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27076/133219 for suggestions.